# Python re (regex) matching particular string containing letters, hyphen, numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to match the following strings in python 2.7 using the python regular expression package re and am having trouble coming up with the regex code:

```
https://www.this.com/john-smith/e5609239
https://www.this.com/jane-johnson/e426609216
https://www.this.com/wendy-saad/e172645609215
https://www.this.com/nick-madison/e7265609214
https://www.this.com/tom-taylor/e17265709211
https://www.this.com/james-bates/e9212
```

So the prefix is fixed "https://www.this.com/" and then there are a variable number of lowercase letters, then "-", then "e", then a variable number of digits.

Here is what I have tried to no avail:

```
href=re.compile("https://www.this.com/people-search/[a-z]+[\-](?P<firstNumBlock>\d+)/")

href=re.compile("https://www.this.com/people-search/[a-z][\-][a-z]+/e[0-9]+")
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into issues with escaping special characters. Since you're not using raw strings, the backslash has special meaning in your string literal itself. Additionally, character classes (with `[]`) don't require escaping in a regular expression. You can simplify your expression as follows:

```
expression = r"https://www.mylife.com/people-search/[a-z]+-[a-z]+/e\d+"
```

With the following data:

```
strings = ['https://www.mylife.com/people-search/john-smith/e5609239',
 'https://www.this.com/people-search/jane-johnson/e426609216',
 'https://www.this.com/people-search/wendy-saad/e172645609215',
 'https://www.this.com/people-search/nick-madison/e7265609214',
 'https://www.this.com/people-search/tom-taylor/e17265709211',
 'https://www.this.com/people-search/james-bates/e9212']
```

Result:

```
>>> for s in strings:
...     print(re.match(expression, s))
...
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 56), match='https://www.this.com/people-search/john-smith/e>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 60), match='https://www.this.com/people-search/jane-johnson>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 61), match='https://www.this.com/people-search/wendy-saad/e>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 61), match='https://www.this.com/people-search/nick-madison>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 60), match='https://www.this.com/people-search/tom-taylor/e>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 54), match='https://www.this.com/people-search/james-bates/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
href=re.compile("https://www\.mylife\.com/people-search/[a-z]+-[a-z]+/e[0-9]+")
```

[Try out here.](https://regex101.com/r/DOnbFF/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
re.compile(r'https://www.this.com/[a-z-]+/e\d+')
```

`[a-z-]+` match `john-smith`
`e\d+` match `e5609239`

Answer (score 1):

```
text = '''https://www.this.com/john-smith/e5609239
https://www.this.com/jane-johnson/e426609216
https://www.this.com/wendy-saad/e172645609215
https://www.this.com/nick-madison/e7265609214
https://www.this.com/tom-taylor/e17265709211
https://www.this.com/james-bates/e9212'''
href = re.compile(r'https://www\.this\.com/[a-zA-Z]+\-[a-zA-Z]+/e[0-9]+')
m = href.findall(text)
pprint(m)
```

Outputs:

```
['https://www.this.com/john-smith/e5609239',
'https://www.this.com/jane-johnson/e426609216',
'https://www.this.com/wendy-saad/e172645609215',
'https://www.this.com/nick-madison/e7265609214',
'https://www.this.com/tom-taylor/e17265709211',
'https://www.this.com/james-bates/e9212']
```